# Exceptions are not handled in assertRaise()

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I am having trouble and difficulties with Pilgrim's Dive into python 3 Unit Testing chapter. I've run the exact same code in romantest2.py. Exceptions are not being handled in the code provided on the examples. I have deduced the example on the book into a smaller snippet:

TestCase1.py

```
import unittest

class ToRomanBadInput(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_too_large(self):
        '''to_roman should fail with large input'''
        self.assertRaises(roman2.OutOfRangeError,roman2.to_roman,4000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

the file roman2.py

```
class OutOfRangeError(ValueError):
    pass

def to_roman(n):
    raise OutOfRangeError("Value n {0} is larger than 3999.".format(n))
```

I can't seem to move on this part. What happen is that I expect the test case to fail.
But it didn't instead it shows:

```
..
------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s
OK
```

I am using and running this code PyDev in Eclipse and the version of python is version 3.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asserting that the `to_roman()` function raises an exception. **That test succeeds**, your function indeed raises the exception.

Comment: Thanks I am so stunned. I am such an idiot. Of course it works! I complete misunderstood unit testing. Now I understand it! This could have saved me a lot of trouble before! Thanks a lot.